# How to convert a string with the name of a class to the class type itself?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, metaprogramming, metaclass

In order to store a class name in a log file I converted the description of a class type to a string:

```
let objectType: NSObject.Type = Object.self
let str = String(describing: objectType)
```

However, I do not succeed in back conversion of `str` to a variable of type `NSObject.Type` to use it in a generic method.

How could I do this?

Comment: You want to create an instance of the type? I'm not sure how this could work given different initializer requirements of different types. Curious if anyone knows a way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get your class back from `string`, but you need to use your project's **module** name while getting class name. If you don't use your module name then it will return `nil` because the class name you have referenced earlier is not fully qualified by the **module name**. You should change the class name string to represent the fully qualified name of your class:

```
let myClassString = String(MyModule.MyViewController.self)
print(myClassString)
let myClass = NSClassFromString("MyModule.\(myClassString)") as! MyViewController.Type
print(myClass)
```

Comment: Indeed, the module name was the missing part!

Answer (score 1):

I simply created an extension to use on any object:

```
extension NSObject {

    // Save Name of Object with this method
    func className() -> String {

        return NSStringFromClass(self.classForCoder)

    }

    // Convert String to object Type
    class func objectFromString(string: String) -> AnyObject? {
        return NSClassFromString(string)
    }

}
```

The method **classForCoder** prints out the module name with the class name. Then you must that string in order to convert it back to its respective object type.

Comment: But how about the conversion from a string to NSObject.Type?

Comment: The self.classForCoder is a good one. I was not aware that the module name was required for the conversion from string to class type. I accepted the other answer since it was posted before this answer. But I really think this answer is useful and I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
let objectType: NSObject.Type = NSObject.self 

let str = String(objectType) // str = "NSObject"

let aClass = NSClassFromString(str) as! NSObject.Type // aClass = NSObject.Type
```

Comment: In my edit I tried to indicate that `Object` is a subclass of `NSObject`. In case `str` contains the class name of ‘Object’ then `NSClassFromString(str)` is still `nil`, unfortunately.

Comment: @pflous would this work with pure swift classes as well?