# How to use a class type in a generic class

Tags: ios, swift, generics, metaprogramming

From a log file I obtain a string that contains the name a class, e.g. "Child" that may be defined as:

```
class Child: Object, MyProtocol {
// ...
}
```

I want to use this class in the following generic class:

```
open class MyClass<T: Object> where T:MyProtocol {
    //…

    open class func doSomething() {
    //…
    }

}
```

I already asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39668370/how-to-convert-a-string-with-the-name-of-a-class-to-the-class-type-itself) how to obtain the class type from a string, which can be obtained by:

```
let objectType = NSClassFromString("MyModule.\(strFromLog)”) as! Object.Type
```

Obviously, `objectType` can not be used directly on `MyClass` since it is of type `T.Type` and not `T`, and the following does not work:

```
MyClass<objectType>.doSomething() // -> error: Use of undeclared type 'objectType'
```

However, is there still a way to use `objectType` in `MyClass` without the need to change the generic class itself (i.e. other methods rely on it)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use result of `NSClassFromString` as a type for your generic class. However, you can workaround this by writing something like this:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
}

extension NSString: SomeProtocol {
}

class SomeClass<T: SomeProtocol> {
  class func doSomething() {
  }
}

if let some = NSClassFromString("NSString") {
  if some is NSString.Type {
    SomeClass<NSString>.doSomething()
    print("String")
  } else {
    print("Not String")
  }
}
```